# Print only one view of a NSSplitView

Tags: cocoa, printing

When printing a view in Cocoa how can I print only one view of a NSSplitView, when is displaying all of its subviews?

In the picture below I would like to print the Header View and the SubView1, not SubView2.

[image]

I know that I could create a new view for printing, but I would like to know if this is possible with what I got.

Thanks

PS: I'm using storyboards

Comment: Call `print:` of the view you want to print.

Comment: Hi. I don't want to only print that view. In the example I would like the header, that is outside the split view, to also print.

Comment: Print the superview of the NSSplitView and the headerview. Override `knowsPageRange:` and `rectForPage:` and return the area you want to print.